# Convert from List<Integer> to array float[]

Tags: java, arraylist, valueconverter

I have a list as follow:

```
List<Integer> arrInt={2,3,5};
```

I want to convert this arraylist to array float.

```
float[] result={2,3,5};
```

My code:

```
    public float[] convertIntToFloat(List<Integer> arr)
    {
      List<Float> arrResult=new ArrayList<Float>();

      for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
      {
        float x=i;
        arrResult.add(x);
      }

      float result[]=arrResult.toArray( new float[arr.size()]);  //Error

      return result;
    }
```

But it display error in my code as above.
Can you help me?

Comment: What error is it showing? And why are you not directly creating `float[]` instead of going through `ArrayList<Float>`?

Comment: Next time please post the error, it will be much more better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`List.toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) takes an array for Wrapper type, not primitive type.

You should do it like this:

```
Float result[] = arrResult.toArray( new Float[arr.size()]);
```

But, that's really not required. Because, now you would have to convert this to primitive type array. That is too much right?

You can directly create a `float[]` array, rather than going through an `ArrayList<Float>`. Just change your `arrResults` declaration to:

```
float[] arrResults = new float[arr.size()];
```

And in for loop, add elements to the array using:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
    arrResults[i] = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Here I want to get float[], isn't Float[].

Comment: @treehh. `float[]` is not the same as `Float[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the `float` array directly:

```
public float[] convertIntToFloat(List<Integer> arr)
{
  float[] arrResult = new float[arr.size()];
  for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
  {
    arrResult[i] = (float) arr[i];
  }

  return arrResult;
}
```

Comment: It's the right idea. It won't *compile*, but it's the right idea... *Edit:* I've fixed it for you. You had two `arrResult` vars (of different types), `arr.length` where you needed `arr.size()`, and various missing semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Generic in Java is limited. You can't use (new float[]) as the parameter of toArray. Use (new Float[]) instead.
However, in fact, a correct implement should be:

```
public float[] convertIntToFloat(List<Integer> arr)
{
  float result = new float[arr.size()];

  for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
  {
      result[i] = arr.get(i);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
public Float[] convertIntToFloat(List<Integer> arr)
    {
      List<Float> arrResult=new ArrayList<Float>();

      for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
      {
        float x=arr.get(i);
//      float x=i;       //Here you are retrieving index instead of value 

        arrResult.add(x);
      }

      Float result[] = arrResult.toArray( new Float[arr.size()]);  
//    float result[]=arrResult.toArray( new float[arr.size()]);  //Error

      return result;
    }
```